# Why 9patch is called 9patch

Tags: android

Why 9patch drawable is called 9patch where this misterious name come from?
I haven't found any information in official documentation.

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

Comment: Sounds like similar : https://www.quora.com/Why-is-9GAG-called-9GAG

Comment: There is an article in our [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/108/resources#t=201607251349148492482) about 9 patches. The first image shows you why they are called like that

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as it is blatently off topic

Comment: @johnny5 Saying "I'm voting to close" **is not** voting to close. I can clearly see that the close vote count is still 0.

Comment: @Rotwang yes, but flagging this in the review queue as off topic, in some way is a vote to close...  I do not have privileges to actually close, I can only vote, to bring this to a vote to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm not sure this question is entirely appropriate for here..Nevertheless here you are:](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2010/06/9-patches/)

> The 9-Patch gets its name from the fact that the overlay created
>   breaks the image up into nine defined regions, organized similar to
>   tic-tac-toe.  Each region has specific stretch properties:
>
> Corner Regions (A,C,G,I) These regions are fixed and nothing inside
>   them will stretch Horizontal Sides (D,F) The pixels in these regions
>   will stretch vertically when necessary Vertical Sides (B,H) The pixels
>   in these regions will stretch horizontally when necessary Center (E)
>   The pixels in this regions will stretch in both horizontal and
>   vertical directions equally